# Google maps <iframe> code not showing properly from wp text editor

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, iframe

I face very weird issue. I get the `iframe` code from google maps and write it into WordPress editor and when I save it and refresh my page it shows me iframe code as it is.

**My iframe code**

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d27095.10477927874!2d115.7941040874009!3d-31.90963766909216!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x2a32ae630473e2ad%3A0x1c04f0b88014a3f0!2sHerdsman+WA+6017%2C+Australia!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1467018866612" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I show it from my contact page, so in page.php I write simple loop

```
if(have_posts()) {
   while(have_posts()) {
      the_post();

      the_content();
   }
}
```

I also change `the_content()` to `get_the_content()` but nothing  happened.

Is some one know what is the issue, why its shows me `<iframe>` code as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add iframe code in to text editor rather then visual editor,
try

[image]